# Edit an EaselJS path without original Flash file?

Tags: javascript, flash, easeljs

I'm trying to edit some text in a graphics object that was created from a Flash EaselJS export. Here is the path I'm trying to edit:

```
this.shape.graphics.f("#FF0000").s().p("AD8HbIgG...
```

And that line goes on for thousands of characters as it's using a custom font.

Is there any way to decode this path and edit the text?

Answer (score 0):

It may be enough for you to have pinpointed that shape in the code.

I would try creating a new Flash Canvas document that only contains your modified object. Publish it, find the shape code and paste it into your pre-existing export.

Comment: Nice idea but I don't have that custom font :(